# Android image processing filters causes OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: android, c++, opencv, bitmap, android-ndk

i have been searching for a good and reliable solution for this problem please help me
The problem is that i am creating image filtering app using OpenCV in Android (C++ ndk) and when i continuously apply filters on a bitmap every time it calls OpenCV native c++ function after converting bitmap into an integer array and passing it into the native c++ function.
Filters work fine and i get result but when i apply them continuously depending on the device the app gives OutOfMemory exception when i am converting the result of filter (integer array) into bitmap again.
On different devices i tested this and the number of times filter is applied successfully is different .
The code line on which i get exception is

```
bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(),Config.ARGB_8888);
```

I dont want to resize images to smaller resolutio can anyone tell me the exact code solution to resolve this issue. I will be really thankful !

Comment: My instinct tells me the integer array is running out of memory on the system. Maybe on the "other systems" you tested it on there is more available RAM or disk space?

Comment: Yes i tested on devices with higher RAM's and it still crashes but the number of time i can continuously apply increases also if resolution of image is smaller then the app crashes after applying filters 100 time continously but i don't want to shrink bitmap to to lower resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was very simple, i was not releasing the arrays in native c++ code.